# How to slice/chop a string using multiple indexes in a panda DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm in need of some advice on the following issue:
I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   ID                   SEQ LEN BEG_GAP END_GAP  
0  A1        AABBCCDDEEFFGG  14       2       4  
1  A1        AABBCCDDEEFFGG  14      10      12
2  B1        YYUUUUAAAAMMNN  14       4       6
3  B1        YYUUUUAAAAMMNN  14       8      12
4  C1  LLKKHHUUTTYYYYYYYYAA  20       7       9
5  C1  LLKKHHUUTTYYYYYYYYAA  20      12      15
6  C1  LLKKHHUUTTYYYYYYYYAA  20      17      18
```

And what I need to get is the `SEQ` that's separated between the different `BEG_GAP` and `END_GAP`. I already have worked it out (thanks to a previous question) for sequences that have only one pair of gaps, but here they have multiple.

This is what the sequences should look like:

```
  ID                   SEQ 
0 A1       AA---CDDEE---GG  
1 B1       YYUU---A-----NN  
2 C1  LLKKHHU---YY----Y--A
```

Or in an exploded DF:

```
  ID Seq_slice
0 A1        AA
1 A1     CDDEE  
2 A1        GG
3 B1      YYUU
4 B1         A   
5 B1        NN
6 C1   LLKKHHU
7 C1        YY
8 C1         Y
9 C1         A
```

At the moment, I'm using a piece of code (that I got thanks to a previous question) that works **only** if there's one gap, and it looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("..\path_to_the_csv.csv")


df["BEG_GAP"] = df["BEG_GAP"].astype(int)
df["END_GAP"]= df["END_GAP"].astype(int)

df['SEQ'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x.SEQ[:x.BEG_GAP], x.SEQ[x.END_GAP+1:]], axis=1)

output = df.explode('SEQ').query('SEQ!=""')
```

But this has the problem that it generates a bunch of sequences that don't really exist because they actually have another gap in the middle.
I.e what it would generate:

```
  ID   Seq_slice
0 A1          AA
1 A1    CDDEEFFG #<- this one shouldn't exist! Because there's another gap in 10-12
2 A1  AABBCCDDEE #<- Also, this one shouldn't exist, it's missing the previous gap.
3 A1          GG
```

And so on, with the other sequences. As you can see, there are some slices that are not being generated and some that are wrong, because I don't know how to tell the code to have in mind **all** the gaps while analyzing the sequence.

All advice is appreciated, I hope I was clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try defining a function and `apply`:

```
def truncate(data):
    seq = data.SEQ.iloc[0]
    ll = data.LEN.iloc[0]
    return [seq[x:y] for x,y in zip([0]+list(data.END_GAP),
                                    list(data.BEG_GAP)+[ll])]

(df.groupby('ID').apply(truncate)
   .explode().reset_index(name='Seq_slice')
)
```

Output:

```
   ID Seq_slice
0  A1        AA
1  A1    CCDDEE
2  A1        GG
3  B1      YYUU
4  B1        AA
5  B1        NN
6  C1   LLKKHHU
7  C1       TYY
8  C1        YY
9  C1        AA
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```py
df.groupby('ID').agg({'BEG_GAP': list, 'END_GAP': list, 'SEQ': max, 'LEN': max}).apply(lambda x: [x['SEQ'][b: e] for b, e in zip([0] + x['END_GAP'], x['BEG_GAP'] + [x['LEN']])], axis=1).explode()
```

```sh
ID
A1         AA
A1     CCDDEE
A1         GG
B1       YYUU
B1         AA
B1         NN
C1    LLKKHHU
C1        TYY
C1         YY
C1         AA
```